# How to Implement Application server

Tags: android

I have to implement a client-server architecture where there are many android client located at different places querying the application server (running all the time (24x7)) and which will do task accordingly and reply to clients. But I don't know what exactly application server is and how to implement it and what is easiest and quickest way to implement this. I am running out of time that is why posting this question otherwise I would have gone through lot of tutorials instead.
The server code is to be written in php/c#/java.

Any quick help is highly appreciated.

Comment: are you streaming data or jsut specific information  and do you need a webService or App-server??

Comment: The server does the work of only sending the current database table (after little edit to the table) to the client who made the request via HTTP protocol to the server. So I think I need an App-server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have look at [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html) its easy to setup, hosted on google environment. Which might fulfill your need. In this case you don't need to buy hosting plans etc. etc. You will get yourappname.appspot.com URL to use app server.

Hope it helps!

Note:
Appengine supports Python and Java

Comment: Can I send HTTP query to that from my android application

Comment: Yes, RECOMMENDED :: READ APP ENGINE DOCS AND MAKE SAMPLE APP,

first write a servlet which can handle your request @see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating.html and then 


make request to that server using, http://yourappengineappid.appspot.com/yourservlet?name=youname&app=android

Comment: WHY THERE AT THE END IT IS GIVEN - "Start the server, then visit the server's URL in your browser. If you're using Eclipse and the Google Eclipse plugin, the server runs using port 8888 by default:*http://localhost:8888/guestbook "  I WANT A SERVER THAT WOULD BE ON THE WEB AND CAN BE CALLED BY THE APPLICATION WHICH IS FAR APART FROM THE SERVER. BUT THEN WHY IS THE "LOCALHOST" THING ?

Comment: Hey, its for local testing perpose so it runs on localhost.
When you deploy it to APPENGINE its live address like http://yourappengineappid.appspot.com 

Few days back i created appengine app see : http://myfavdroidapps.appspot.com/


read : 
Start from here : https://appengine.google.com/start
getting started : http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/

http://www.vogella.de/articles/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html

Comment: just for a query before i proceed .. would i be able to maintain database there in the appengine ?

Comment: yes, there's data store and other storage mechanism in appengine. but theres nothing like mysql or sql stuff! have some search on this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5645/discussion-between-visd-and-piyushnp)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it by knowing how the application servers work.


First of all, you should create a class that implements the **HttpHandler**, in handle method you can get header and body of the message.


Secondly, you should choose how to handle the request in HttpHandler. One possible approach can be using of **ThreadPoolTaskExecutor** or **SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor** or any task executors.

 Finally, you should prepare the response messsage with ***exchange.getResponseHeaders() and  exchange.getResponseBody()***